# php mysql how to break down 10:30 with php mathematings

Tags: php, mysql

i'm making a Time registration site but i'm unclear on how i would go about with some of the mathematics.
example:

```
$shiftstart = 10:30
$shiftend = 20:45
```

i'm at a lose how to do the mathematics for this:
i need them to be broken down like this:
`$shiftstart` double `10,00 = $shifthours` so i separate the first to digits and then the last to digits as double `0,30 = $shiftminuts`
then do `$shiftminuts(0,30) * 1,666666666667` so it'l = `0,50`

also how would i go about using this in a function?

also what would be the best approach of storing values as `10:30 - 21:35` int or varchar in my mysql table?

btw i'm writing in php
thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Use minutes for everything - both calculations and storage. Only convert to hours when you display it. If you're only concerned about times within a single day (as it appears) then use the offset from midnight for all values.

---

EDIT:

10:30 = (10*60) + 30. All math is done using minutes rather than trying to split hours as float.

Comment: can i get you to elaborate that?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding time math: I would prefer to create a class inherited from DateTime http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php that encapsulates your logic.
Also, I haven't got from the question, is 10:30 somehow related to any date?
If yes, you should use datetime/timestamp types in mysql.
If not, you can use varchar to store '10:30' as a string.

Also, you have another option: store and manipulate in seconds (minutes).
In this case, you can create a value object class for calculations and use int as a type in mysql.

What about DST? Does 10:30 will be 11:30 in those dates? Or still will be 10:30? You should be ready for that. And keep in mind that in different countries it starts in different dates. This is why I prefer to use built-in DateTime class.

Comment: Thanks ethrbunny, and alex13 you've been a great help :D